# KQL for Security Recommendations

Tags: azure, kql

I have 2 queries calling for "assessment name" and "securescorecontrols display name". As we see in Azure, assessments are always under Secure score controls in Defender for Cloud Recommendations. Is it possible to combine these 2 queries so that I can visualize it just like in Azure?

**microsoft.security/assessments**

```
`securityresources
| where type == "microsoft.security/assessments"
| extend name = properties.displayName
| extend resourceDetails = properties.resourceDetails
| extend resourceName = resourceDetails.ResourceName
| extend statusDetails = properties.status
| extend status = statusDetails.code
| extend metadata = properties.metadata
| extend severity = metadata.severity
| join kind=leftouter  ( 
    resourcecontainers
        | where type == "microsoft.resources/subscriptions"
        | extend resolvedSubId = tostring(split(id, '/', 2)[0]), subscriptionName = name
        | project resolvedSubId, subscriptionName
) on $left.subscriptionId == $right.resolvedSubId
| project name, subscriptionName, resourceName, status,severity`
```

**microsoft.security/securescores/securescorecontrols**

```
 securityresources
    | where type == "microsoft.security/securescores/securescorecontrols"
    | extend name = properties.displayName
    | extend healthy = properties.healthyResourceCount
    | extend unhealthy = properties.unhealthyResourceCount
    | extend notApplicable = properties.notApplicableResourceCount
    | extend score = properties.score
    | extend scr= parse_json(score)
    | project name, healthy, unhealthy, notApplicable, CurrentScore=scr.current, MaxScore=scr.max`
```

I tried the join kind query but I'm not sure what to put after "on" and I'm not familiar with "join" overall.

Comment: Are you executing the query in resource graph explorer? @Vince

Answer (score 0):

*Use below query with `let` and `join` operators to combine your two queries for better visualization.*

```bash
let assessments = 
    securityresources
    | where type == "microsoft.security/assessments"
    | extend name = properties.displayName
    | extend resourceName = properties.resourceDetails.ResourceName
    | extend status = properties.status.code
    | extend metadata = properties.metadata
    | extend severity = metadata.severity
    | project name, resourceName, status, severity

let secure =
    securityresources
    | where type == "microsoft.security/securescores/securescorecontrols"
    | extend name = properties.displayName
    | extend healthy = properties.healthyResourceCount
    | extend unhealthy = properties.unhealthyResourceCount
    | extend notApplicable = properties.notApplicableResourceCount
    | extend score = properties.score
    | extend scr= parse_json(score)
    | project name, healthy, unhealthy, notApplicable, CurrentScore=scr.current, MaxScore=scr.max

assessments
| join kind=fullouter secure on name
| project name, resourceName, status, severity, healthy, unhealthy, notApplicable, CurrentScore, MaxScore
```

[image]

*Reference:* [Let](https://cybergeeks.cloud/2021/07/kql-fundamentals-let/) in KQL.